# Slow query performance on SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, azure, azure-sql-database

I have built a document management system for my company.  A desktop application connects to an ASP.Net Web API, hosted as an Azure Web App, which connects to an Azure SQL database.

As my database has become more populated, it is starting to slow down significantly so I need help with doing so query optimizations.  Here is the Linq query that is currently causes me problems.  Basically this query captures all the projects from the database and then populates a list in my desktop application

```
    var projects = (from p in db.Projects.Include(c => c.ProjectType)

                            select new
                            {
                                ID = p.ID,
                                HasSubProjects = (db.Projects.Where(u => u.ParentProjectID == p.ID).Count() > 0) ? 1 : 0,
                                ParentProjectID = p.ParentProjectID,
                                Name = p.Name,
                                Description = p.Description,
                                DateLastEdited = p.DateLastEdited,
                                DateCreated = p.DateCreated,
                                ProjectTypeID = p.ProjectTypeID,
                                LastEditedByGoesby = p.LastEditedByGoesby,
                                ProjectComponentSecurityType = p.ProjectComponentSecurityType,
                                ClonedFrom = p.ClonedFrom,
                                DateAnyVersionLastEditedByUser = p.DateAnyVersionLastEditedByUser,
                                DateAnyVersionLastEdited = p.UserProjectActivityLookups
                                    .OrderByDescending(u => u.LastActivityDate)
                                    .Select(v => v.LastActivityDate)
                                    .FirstOrDefault(),
                                // p.DateAnyVersionLastEdited,,
                                ProjectType = p.ProjectType

                            }).ToList()
                .Select(x2 => new Project
                {
                    ID = x2.ID,
                    HasSubProjects = x2.HasSubProjects,
                    ParentProjectID = x2.ParentProjectID,
                    Name = x2.Name,
                    Description = x2.Description,
                    DateLastEdited = x2.DateLastEdited,
                    DateCreated = x2.DateCreated,
                    ProjectTypeID = x2.ProjectTypeID,
                    LastEditedByGoesby = x2.LastEditedByGoesby,
                    ProjectComponentSecurityType = x2.ProjectComponentSecurityType,
                    ClonedFrom = x2.ClonedFrom,
                    DateAnyVersionLastEditedByUser = x2.DateAnyVersionLastEditedByUser,
                    DateAnyVersionLastEdited = x2.DateAnyVersionLastEdited,
                    ProjectType = x2.ProjectType
                });
            ;
```

Any ideas on how to optimize this, avoid problems related to this query, create indexes better or using standard procedures etc would be helpful.  I'm looking for direction on this specific query but also any guidance on how I can improve my performance on other queries and how to go about doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the usual idea would be to ask the database for a query plan. Missing indexes can be spotted fairly easy from there.

Comment: what Azure SQL database service tier / performance level are you on? Is it Basic by any chance?

Comment: How many entries does your database contain? At some point in time (or rather DB fill level) your application just won't be able to load all into memory, regardless of indexes. Then you'll need to change strategy at application level, e.g. by paging or on-demand loading of lists and UI elements.

Comment: @ajg - "Is it Basic by any chance?" - and Standard isn't much better. :(

Comment: how many entries are being retrieved by this query? 100? 10000?

Comment: There are 943 projects in the db right now.  I'm using the Standard tier.

Comment: Not sure why you are first projecting into an anonymous type, and then reprojecting into Project.  I see no differences.  You are populating a lot of data for a "list", do you always show all the fields, or could you possibly reduce some of the data by not calling .ToList so early and filtering down the actual columns you are going to use?

Comment: @Robert, I guess the projection into different types makes no difference for query performance in the database, though.

Comment: Of course it does.  You are creating and destroying an anonymous object unnecessarily instead of just putting it into the Project class initially.

Comment: @Robert, good question...I wrote this code a while ago and I can't recall why I did it this way...I will try to simplify this query and see if I can figure out why I did it this way to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for going about is to find out what sql query this code is generating. Then try to see what is the issue with that sql query and accordingly change your linq query.

Some things that you should look for:

1. `ParentProjectID`, check for the indexes and try to join instead of subquery.
2. Similarly check for `DateAnyVersionLastEdited`, since the query is going against the all user data. This could slow you down if this has a lot of data and bad indexes.
3. Last thing I would recommend to have a where clause depending upon the data you are retrieving.

So, if you are ultimately retrieving records in *thousands*, then try to restrict the count either by paging or by some other business condition.

Comment: I think the problem may be in your #2 above as there are a lot of "Versions".    I will check this and report back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL database has several built in tools that provide query optimization help.

- [Query Store](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-azure-sql-database-query-store/) acts as "flight data recorder" for queries to get the data on query plans, execution times and to find most expensive queries. You can look at the execution statistics for your query above to see if there are any obvious problems.
- [Index advisor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-index-advisor/) analyzes the historical resource usage and provides index advice and monitors the index usage
- Various [dynamic management views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188068.aspx) (DMVs) like dm_exec_query_stats provide query execution statistics information
- MSDN article on [azure sql database performance guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx) provides a high level performance guidance information

Azure SQL database shares common codebase with SQL Server. So, most of the query optimization techniques used for SQL Server will also apply here. Bing/Google search on SQL Server query optimization will provide lots of pointers.

Srini Acharya